# Problem with decoding json to List<Object> in FLUTTER

Tags: json, flutter, dart, decode, listobject

Hi i'm a beginer in flutter and currentely struggling with **json**. I need to deposit `List<ShoppingItem>` in shared_preferences, which i managed to do with code below, but later I have a problem with **decoding it back**. Just for  better understanding - i'm building a simple shopping list app, and i want to save a list of products on a phone, so that after restarting the app the list would't be lost.

---

```
class ShoppingItem with ChangeNotifier {
  String name;
  String quantity;
  bool isPurchased;
  String unit;

  ShoppingItem({
    @required this.name = '',
    this.quantity = '',
    this.unit = '',
    this.isPurchased = false,
  });

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'quantity': quantity,
    'isPurchased': isPurchased,
    'unit': unit,
  };
```

My encoding code:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
enProd = json.encode(_newProduct.toJson());
jsonList.add(enProd);
prefs.setStringList('jsonList', jsonList);
print(jsonList);
```

Just for the record, after adding 3 different products to my list i'm getting this output in terminal, which looks ok:

```
[{name: Product 1, quantity: 4, isPurchased: false, unit: kg}, 
{name: Product 2, quantity: 5, isPurchased: false, unit: }, 
{name: Product 3, quantity: , isPurchased: false, unit: }]
```

And here **my problem begins**, list obtaining code below:

```
Future<void> getList() async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final a = json.decode(prefs.getStringList('jsonList').toString());
print(a);
products = a;
```

After calling this method i'm getting an error:

> `List<dynamic>` is not a subtype of type `List<ShoppingItem>`

I tried changing definition of a to be `final List<ShoppingItem> a = ...`
Probably it is not a very hard question to answer, however i checked a lot of sollutions from the internet and i'm really confused rn. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note of concern. You are saying you are new to Flutter but your code is written without null-safety (so Dart 2.10 or lower). Any specific reason for this? Because it could mean you are following an old tutorial which I would not recommend.

Comment: `json.decode()` return list or map as far as I know, not directly as ShoppingItem. You have to unpack the decoded collection yourself and then construct ShoppingItem. You can check an [example](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes) here. There you can see `fromJson` constructor.

Comment: Create a factory that generates a ShoppoingItem object from a json and then a method to create a List of ShoppingItem that calls that factory